# Automating web deployments in C#

Tags: c#, .net, deployment

Can anyone recommend any tools for automating the deployment of web services and web sites to IIS. It would also be useful to have the ability to run nunit(tests) following the deployment and to possibly rollback if they fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) tools (TeamCity, CruisControl, Jenkins, TFS etc...) can be used for this.

After your build step, you can add testing steps and if these are all successful, a deployment step to the live environment.

Details of how to do so vary between the different tools, but they are all capable.

Comment: I want the testing to be done following the deployment to verify that the deployment was successful

Comment: @Dunc - And you can do that if you wish, including your rollback. These tools are all very flexible.

Comment: Can you interact with IIS from Jenkins\Hudson

Comment: @Dunc - No tool does that natively. What do you mean by "interact"? In what way? There are testing tools (Selenium) that do, there are libraries for managing IIS as well. All of which _can_ be controlled by CI tools.

Comment: By interact I mean stop/start IIS

Comment: @Dunc - You can use them to call `IISReset` and even configure the passed in server name if wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I have used successfully [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) for similar case than what you describe. TeamCity should be more than capable for your particular problem.

Build and/or unit test failure will prevent automatic deploy.

If you could describe more your requirements (max cost, licensing, personal/business etc.) then I could evaluate more is it suitable for your.